# I'm trying to make an Android app using Android Processing for the visual side, and puredata for sound synthesis. Is this feasible?

Tags: java, android, tcp, udp, processing

I'm trying to build a sound toy for Android, and I'm the most familiar with [Processing](http://processing.org/) for the visual side, which has been ported for Android. I want to use [Puredata](http://puredata.info/) for sound, because at the moment it seems like the best option for dsp on Android. [I've been told on the Processing forums](http://forum.processing.org/topic/can-anyone-give-me-an-idea-of-how-to-use-puredata-with-processing-for-android) that the best way to communicate with Processing through Puredata is to use TCP or UDP messages. I have no idea how to do this, because I am creating the .apk in the Processing environment and I don't see how I can launch the Puredata patch through Processing. Would this only be possible in pure Java? Or would I somehow have to launch a separate Puredata app at the same time. And are there any good resources for learning how to send TCP/UDP messages? Any help would be appreciated, and I can clarify if it makes it easier.

EDIT: It seems as if OSC uses the TCP protocol, so I'm not really sure why I can't use OSC. The only part I'm confused about is how to package the Processing sketch and the Puredata patch into one APK.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the specifics of android platform development, but you would need to be able to run one app from within the other. [This stack overflow question shows you how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807671/how-do-you-run-a-shell-script-inside-of-an-android-app). Once you have done that, you will be able to send commands over osc to you pd instance.

Another option would be using [libpd](http://gitorious.org/pdlib). According to one of the devs, they are working on [packing it up as a processing lib](http://createdigitalmusic.com/2010/10/libpd-put-pure-data-in-your-app-on-an-iphone-or-android-and-everywhere-free/). If you wrote your visual code in c, then you would be able to link down to this libpd for your audio processing.